# yii2 sort with dropdown

Tags: sorting, yii2, dropdown

I have problem with sorting in listview yii2. I don't know how can I create dropdown list with sorting in Separate filter form.

In model I have:

```
$dataProvider->sort->attributes['sort'] = [
            'asc' => ['game.rating' => SORT_ASC],
            'desc' => ['game.rating' => SORT_DESC],
        ];
```

but how create drop down?

Model:

```
class GameSearch extends Offer
{

    public $status;
    public $title;
    public $type;
    public $platform;
    public $rating;
    public $pageSize;
    public $sort;


    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['status', 'platform', 'pageSize'], 'integer'],
            [['title', 'type', 'sort', 'rating'], 'string']
        ];
    }

    public function search($params, $query)
    {
        $query->joinWith(['game', 'author']);


        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
            'sort' => ['defaultOrder' => ['created_at' => SORT_DESC]],
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => $this->pageSize,
            ],
        ]);

        $dataProvider->sort->attributes['sort'] = [
            'asc' => ['game.rating' => SORT_ASC],
            'desc' => ['game.rating' => SORT_DESC],
        ];

        if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        $dataProvider->pagination->pageSize = $this->pageSize;

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'game.title', $this->title])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'platform', $this->platform]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

and my search file

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'sort')
                ->dropDownList([
                    'rating' => 'rating ASC',
                    '-rating' => 'rating DESC',
                ])
                ->label(false)
                ->error(false);
            ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

i have same proplem, and here is my config
View. Value 1 is sort ASC and value 2 is sort DESC

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'sort')
            ->dropDownList([
                '1' => 'rating ASC',
                '2' => 'rating DESC',
            ],['id' =>'find-rating1'])
            ->label(false)
            ->error(false);
        ?>
```

and add js bottom of view

```
$findUrl = Url::current([], true);
$pos = strpos($findUrl, '&rating');
if($pos){
    $findUrl = substr($findUrl, 0 , $pos);
}
$app_js = <<<JS
    $("#find-rating1").change(function() {
        var rating_value= $(this).val();
        location.href="$findUrl" +"&rating="+rating_value;
    });
JS;
$this->registerJs($app_js);
```

As you see, when dropdown has change event. will redirect to url will rating param 1 or 2. So in Controller you can get rating value 1 or 2 and set sortting.

```
 $ratingValue = getParam('rating', 1);
```

and with $ratingValue you can customize you search query

Comment: Demo url http://cubic1.jp/search/find-employees?type=1 in area http://prntscr.com/cw2weu

Answer (score 0):

A little late but I found this post when searching for a similar issue and
 hopefully what I ended up doing helps others.

Add the bootstrap classes to the ListView sorter `<ul>`. Also, set whatever attributes you want in the list or leave that part out if you want to see everything.

```
'sorter' => [
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'dropdown-menu'
    ],
    'attributes' => [
        'id', 'name'
    ]
],
```

Then wrap that in the rest of the bootstrap dropdown tags with `layout`. This example puts the `sorter` above the `items`, `pager` and `summary`.

```
'layout' => '
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Sort <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        {sorter}
    </div>
{items}{pager}{summary}
',
```

Then style away!